# Get value of hidden input using jquery parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the value that is stored inside hidden input field. 'onchange' or 'onfocusout' events I am invoking JavaScript function, but I am unable to get the right value inside 'id' variable.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row-wrapper">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenID" class="hiddenID" value="1" />
    <table class="default-table">

        <tr>
            <th>Client <em>*</em>
            </th>
            <th>Project <em>*</em>
            </th>
            <th>Category <em>*</em>
            </th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th class="small">Time <em>*</em>
            </th>
            <th class="small">Overtime</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="client" class='client' onchange='return update(event, "client");'>
                    <option>Choose client</option>
                    <option>Client 1</option>
                    <option>Client 2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="project" class='project' onchange='return update(event, "project");'>
                    <option>Choose project</option>
                    <option>Project 1</option>
                    <option>Project 2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>Choose category</option>
                    <option>Front-End Development</option>
                    <option>Design</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="in-text medium" name="description"/>
            </td>
            <td class="small">
                <input type="text" class="in-text xsmall" name="time" />
            </td>
            <td class="small">
                <input type="text" class="in-text xsmall" name="time" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

And this is my script for now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[name=description]').focusout(function () {
            update($(this), 'description');
        });

        $('input[name=time]').focusout(function () {
            update($(this), 'time');
            calculate();
        });

        function update(event, type) {
            var id = $(event.target).parent().find('.hiddenID').val();
            var this_element = $(event.target).val();
            alert('id: ' + id + ' this element val: ' + this_element + ' this element is: ' + type);

            $(event.target).parent().find('.id').val();

            return false;
        }
</script>
```

What is a proper way of using parent() function in jquery? I was reading the documentation and as I've understood parent() finds only parent div tag. Is there some other function that can work with tables and find the hidden input that is in the same div tag as table is?

Comment: Use `$(event.target).closest('.row-wrapper').find('.hiddenID').val();`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for answering, but I still get 'undefined' value for id. So parent definitely can't access to the div tag when you using tables?

Comment: You need to pass `event` instead if `this` in `update($(this), 'time');`  like `$('input[name=time]').focusout(function (event) { update(event, 'time');......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your update() function :

New Code :

```
    function update(event, type) {
        var id = $(event.target).closest('.row-wrapper').find('.hiddenID').val();
        var this_element = $(event.target).val();
        alert('id: ' + id + ' this element val: ' + this_element + ' this element is: ' + type);

        $(event.target).parent().find('.id').val();

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the name in quotes: $('input[name="id"]')

or $('[name="id"]').val();